# Implement the existing RichText editor in jQuery form

Tags: wss-3.0, rich-text, custom-form

I have been working hard to develop custom forms that are completely done in jQuery/javascript. I can create all of the fields I want except for the richtext editor fields. I know sharepoint uses some core javascript files to render these on the screen. I just want to use them on my form. I am displaying the forms in a jQueryUI dialog and using Marc Anderson's SPServices library to add the data to the lists which works fine. Can this be done and what do I need to do to get this functionality in my form.

Comment: I should have stated that I am trying to do this without 3rd party controls as most of those will not be approved for use on our network.  It is sad because the 2 suggestions for editors are good, just not in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of the functions you need are in Form.js in the 12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033 folder (assuming an english install of WSS 3.0/MOSS 2007.)  You may also need HtmlEditor.js and AssetPicker.js depending on which aspects of the toolbar you are rendering.  I have never even attempted to do what you are suggesting and these functions are not documented so you will need to work that out for yourself.

Is it seriously a business requirement that the whole list form renders in a dialog?  Or are you just establishing a POC/R&D?

Additionally you could use the Telerik RADEditor Lite for MOSS its the last link on the page, oh yes and its free.  Its also cross browser compatible (if that is an authoring issue for you.)

http://www.telerik.com/community/free-products.aspx

Comment: I actually decided to cheat and I wrote a webpart that uses an ascx page with the controls I need. I added this webpart to a custom aspx page with a custom master page and then used the jQueryUI to open an iframe where I set the source to the custom page. I can get at the open 'dialog' using jQuery and it is working well!

Answer (score 3):

What about using TinyMCE? http://tinymce.moxiecode.com? That one's very easy to implement.

Comment: yeah, and the good thing is that it only requires a textarea as its "target"